# How can I get fout to work in a function that is not main?

Tags: c++, function, file-io

I am attempting to write to a file using functions that are not a part of main, but whenever I call fout in a function that is not main I get an error stating that fout is not declared in this scope. Here is my header for the file, followed by an example of one of the functions I am attempting to use fout in.
header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cctype>
using namespace std;
```

function:

```
void isCorrectStartingLetter(string currentLine, bool &truthValue)
{
    if(isalpha(currentLine.at(0)))
    {
        truthValue = true;
    }
    else
    {
        truthValue = false;
        fout << "   Error- Must start with a letter" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where did you exactly declare `fout` ?

Comment: Pass it as an argument. I would also highly recommend returning a bool instead of the reference parameter. And I would even moreso recommend **never** doing `using namespace foo;` in a header.

Comment: I hope you chose such name for function not intentionally

Comment: You have realised that to use currentLine and truthValue in isCorrectStartingLetter you must pass them as parameters. Well it's exactly the same for fout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define the function the following way

```
bool isCorrectStartingLetter( const std::string &currentLine, std::ostream &fout = std::cout )
{
    bool truthValue = isalpha(currentLine[0] );


    if ( !truthValue )
    {
        fout << "   Error- Must start with a letter" << endl;
    }

    return truthValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hoping you ain't thinking `fout` is a magical keyword, you should be able to pass it as refernce and accordingly returning `true` or `false`, something like following :-

```
  //std::ofstream fout("file_name");

   bool isCorrectStartingLetter(string currentLine, std::ostream& fout)
    {
        if(isalpha(currentLine.at(0)))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            fout << "   Error- Must start with a letter" << endl;
            return false;

        }
    }
```